# How to add facebook Pixel on Next.js react app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, facebook-pixel

I know this may be a dumb question.
How can I do to use facebook pixel on a next.js react app ?

Answer (score 50):

there are no dumb questions.

You can see nextjs example about how implements fb pixel.
[Nextjs Facebook Pixel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-facebook-pixel)

Comment: Not working for me (Next 13). `/scripts/pixel.js` doesn't seem to exist in `next/script`

Answer (score 24):

Solution with typescript and hook with NextJs

1. Install [react-facebook-pixel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-pixel) `yarn add react-facebook-pixel`
2. In your file `_app.tsx`

```
// pages/_app.tsx

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    import('react-facebook-pixel')
      .then((x) => x.default)
      .then((ReactPixel) => {
        ReactPixel.init('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') // facebookPixelId
        ReactPixel.pageView()

        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
          ReactPixel.pageView()
        })
      })
  }, [router.events])

  

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default App
```

Remark: it works with typescript or JavaScript

Comment: +1 - This worked for me. One thing to note is that even though this example and the react-facebook-library mentions Typescript, the same works with normal Javascript as well.

Comment: True. I will add a comment in my answer.

Comment: Might be trival, but good practive :) Remeber to run `router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', fn)` as the return statement in `useEffect`

Comment: Do you know, are there some version compatibility issues? I don't see the pixel when I do view page source. No errors though..

Comment: P.S. Never mind, found out with the Facebook Pixel Helper extension that I had to turn the adblocker off. :)

Answer (score 13):

Use the new [Script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) component released in Next.js version 11. Import the below into your `_app.js`.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import {pageview, FB_PIXEL_ID} from '../../lib/fpixel'
import Script from 'next/script'

const handleRouteChange = () => {
  pageview()
}

const FB_PIXEL_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID

const pageview = () => {
  window.fbq('track', 'PageView')
}

const FacebookPixel = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    // the below will only fire on route changes (not initial load - that is handled in the script below)
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    }
  }, [router.events])

  return (
    <Script id="facebook-pixel">
      {`
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
        {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
        if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
        n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
        'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq('init', ${FB_PIXEL_ID});
        fbq('track', 'PageView');
      `}
    </Script>
  )
}

export default FacebookPixel
```

##### UPDATE

Do not use `strategy="lazyOnload"`. I was previously using this and the script was more likely to be blocked by adblocker if using this method.

Comment: That is exactly what I need, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There's a library for React called `react-facebook-pixel`. In order to make it work with NextJs, try this solution in your _app.jsx file:

```js
function FacebookPixel() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    import("react-facebook-pixel")
      .then((x) => x.default)
      .then((ReactPixel) => {
        ReactPixel.init('pixel ID here');
        ReactPixel.pageView();

        Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {
          ReactPixel.pageView();
        });
      });
  });
  return null;
}


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"
        />
      </Head>
      <FacebookPixel />
      //…
      <main className="routesContainer">
        <Component siteData={siteData} {...pageProps} />
      </main>
      //…
    </>
  );
}
```

or in case you're using Class components, insert this in you componentDidMount() inside the App class:

```js
  componentDidMount() {

    import('react-facebook-pixel')
      .then((x) => x.default)
      .then((ReactPixel) => {
        ReactPixel.init('Pixel ID Here');
        ReactPixel.pageView();

        Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
          ReactPixel.pageView();
        });
      });
  }
```

font: https://github.com/zsajjad/react-facebook-pixel/issues/53

Answer (score 5):

Simple and easy:

Put the below code inside `_app.js`:

```
useEffect(async () => {
        const { default: ReactPixel } = await import('react-facebook-pixel');
        ReactPixel.init(FB_PIXEL, null, {
            autoConfig: true,
            debug: true,
          });
        ReactPixel.pageView();
        ReactPixel.track("ViewContent")
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Next Js App Router:**

**Path:** src/app/layout.jsx

```
  export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
      return (
        <html lang='en' suppressHydrationWarning>
          <Script id='fb-pixel' strategy='afterInteractive'>
            {`
              !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
              {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
              n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
              if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
              n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
              t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
              s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
              'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
              fbq('init', '${process.env.FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID}');
              fbq('track', 'PageView');
            `}
          </Script>
    
          <body className={openSans.className}>
            <noscript>
              <img
                height='1'
                width='1'
                style='display:none'
                alt={'facebook pixel no script image'}
                src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1002246091049642&ev=PageView&noscript=1'
              />
            </noscript>
          </body>
        </html>
      )

}
```

Comment: Is the 'suppressHydrationWarning' necessary? Thanks!